# How to define $\mathbb{E}[X|X<y]$ formally

Tags: probability, definition, conditional-expectation

In my introduction to probability theory lecture we defined $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ to be the random Variable Z with the properties:

1. $Z=g(Y)$ where g is measureable
2. $\int_{\{Y\in B\}}ZdP=\int_{\{Y\in B\}}XdP$

Which ends up being a.s. unique and in the special case where X and Y are absolute continuous distributed you get $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]=\int x\phi(x|Y)dx$ where $\phi(x|y)=\frac{\phi(x,y)}{\phi_Y(y)}$ with $\phi(x,y)$ the common distribution and $\phi_Y(y)$ the distributino of Y.

You can also define $P(A|Y)=\mathbb{E}[1_A|Y]$. So I could write $P(X<y\mid Y)$.

But the question is kind of how to do the opposite: $\mathbb{E}[X|X<y]$ or more generally $\mathbb{E}[X|A]$ which was used in a game theory lecture. Where the lecturer basically just defined $X|X<y$ to have the density $\frac{\phi_X(x)1_{x<y}}{P(X<y)}$.

And this kind of makes intuitive sense but I wonder how to unify this with the abstract definition of an expected value I learned in my probability theory lectures.

Comment: Formally, for an event $C$ of positive probability, $E[X\mid C] = \frac{E[X\mathbf{1}_C]}{P(C)}$.

Comment: @zhoraster That is the direct definition that the lecturer in game theory basically did since that follows straight from the definition of the density. But I am looking for an axiomatic definition like in the case of $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ unless there is a reason that this fundamentally can't be defined axiomatically, then I would like an explanation of what is different. I mean this looks really similar it should have similar definitions or not?

Comment: What do you mean by 'axiomatic definition'?

Comment: @zhoraster A definition by properties just like in the case of $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$

Comment: So if I say, '$E[X\mid C] $ is a constant $a$ such that $E[X\mathbf{1}_C]=E[a\mathbf{1}_C]$', would this be an 'axiomatic definition'?

Comment: Yes, I guess. The definition of an inverse is for example the element b such that b*a=1 and then you can show that the inverse is unique. You of course could also just directly define the inverse of p/q a as q/p if you operate on the rational numbers for example. But usually the axiomatic definition generalises better. As in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want I think.

Your lecturer aims at the conditional random variable $X$ which takes on only values below $y$. In that sense, the shape of the density of $X$ is the same, only its support is now on the interval $(-\infty,y]$ which gives the scaling factor of $1/P(X<y)$.

On the other hand, you might view $X<y$ as a random variable which takes on the value $1$ if $X<y$ and $0$ if $X\geq y$. In that case, which is essentially the more formal one. You get:
$$ E(X|X<y) = \frac{1}{P(X<y)} \int_{-\infty}^{y} x f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d} x\cdot \mathbb{1}_{X<y} + \frac{1}{P(X\geq y)} \int_{y}^{\infty} x f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d} x\cdot \mathbb{1}_{X\geq y}. $$

**Edit:** Even more formally, you actually have to find the sigma algebra that corresponds to $X<y$. In this case, it is $$\mathcal{A}=\{\varnothing,\{\omega:\ X(\omega)<y\},\{\omega:\ X(\omega)\geq y\},\Omega\}. $$
The conditional expectation is now equal to
$$ E(X|X<y) = E(X|\mathcal{A}) $$
You now have to check that for all $A\in\mathcal{A}$, we have
$$ \int_A \left(\frac{1}{P(X<y)} \int_{-\infty}^{y} x f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d} x\cdot \mathbb{1}_{X<y}(\omega) + \frac{1}{P(X\geq y)} \int_{y}^{\infty} x f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d} x\cdot \mathbb{1}_{X\geq y}(\omega)\right) \,\mathrm{d} \omega = \int_A X(\omega) \,\mathrm{d}\omega $$
Let's take for example $A=\{\omega:\ X(\omega)<y\}$ (the empty set and the complete set are easy, $A^\complement$ is similar), then we get here that $\mathbb{1}_{X\geq y}(\omega) = 0$ on $A$, $\mathbb{1}_{X<y}(\omega) = 1$ on $A$. Note that $P(X < y) = P(A)$ and we get on the left-hand side
$$ \frac{1}{P(A)} \int_A  \int_{-\infty}^{y} x f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d} x \cdot \mathbb{1}_{X < y}(\omega)\,\mathrm{d} \omega = \int_{-\infty}^{y} x f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d} x \cdot \frac{1}{P(A)} \int_A \mathbb{1}_{X < y}(\omega)\,\mathrm{d} \omega = \int_{-\infty}^{y} x f_X(x)\,\mathrm{d} x = E(X\mathbb{1}_{X<y}). $$
Moreover, the right-hand side can be seen as follows (note that $\omega \in A$ is equivalent to $X(\omega) < y$)
$$ \int_A X(\omega)\,\mathrm{d}\omega = \int_\Omega X(\omega)\mathbb{1}_{\omega \in A}\,\mathrm{d}\omega = \int_\Omega X(\omega)\mathbb{1}_{X(\omega)\leq y}\,\mathrm{d}\omega = E(X\mathbb{1}_{X\leq y}). $$

**Edit2**: You also have to note that the expression for the conditional expectation is measurable. This is of course quite trivial for me since I took a few courses in these topics. However, to give a complete answer, I will give the reasoning for this argument. Since $X$ is a random variable, the indicator 'random variables' $\mathbb{1}_{X<y}$ and $\mathbb{1}_{X\geq y}$ are measurable. Moreover, linear combinations of measurable functions are measurable. Hence, it is indeed measureable.

Comment: So you are saying $Z:=1_{(\infty,y)}(X)$ then $\mathbb{E}[X|X<y]=\mathbb{E}[X|Z]$? because that kind of has the issue that the result is a random variable. While the definition via the densities result in a number. And shoudn't I get the same thing just like if I would define the conditional expectation with the conditional density results in the same object in the end?

Comment: The official definition of a conditional expectation is that it equals a random variable satisfying some properties

Comment: However, as I said at the top of my answer, it is a number if you consider the 'conditioning' part to be part of the random variable but that it is not the idea of a conditional expectation in your definition, that is just a normal expectation if you know what I mean.

Comment: yes but that is because it depends on the Y - it is a function of Y as per the first requirement right? So if Y is realized as y then $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ becomes $\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]$ right? which is a number. And in the case $\mathbb{E}[X|X>y]$ I should get a constant expectation for a constant y, no?

Comment: To be even more precise, if you take $\omega\in A$ and calculate the conditional expectation you get the same answer as you would in your case.

Comment: You first should get rid of the idea that conditional expectations are numbers, they aren't.

Comment: Well by conditon 1: $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]=g(Y)$ where g is measureable. So for a realized Y the conditional expectation is realized aka a number. It seems weird that in the case of $\mathbb{E}[X|X<y]$ this should be different. I mean I know for sure that X is smaller than y. So I can form an expectation on X given that it is smaller than a constant number y, right?

Comment: That is what you learn in basic probability classes, because that is kind of useful and easy to calculate. However, you shouldn't view $E[X|Y=y]$ where $Y$ has the realization $y$ because this is not how conditional expectations are defined. The only correct way to define conditional expectations is by using sigma-algebras. Then, you can condition on random variables by saying, we use the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the random variable. You can condition on events by using the indicator random variable. In my answer I explained the details of how that would work. I hope this is more clear?

Comment: So you are saying that $\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]$ is a number for a realized Y as y in the same sense that $\mathbb{E}[X|1_A(X)=1]$ is a number. I.e. $1_A(X)$ is realized as 1 so we get the conditional expectation of $X\in A$? If that makes some sense then I think I got it.

Comment: I am not saying that it is a number, it is a random variable. However, in basic probability classes you are taught it is a number because that is convenient. Maybe it is more clear if I put like: you condition on an event but it is not per se the case that this event happens. So, $E(X|X\leq y) = E(X|X>y)$ because they both generate the same sigma algebra.

Comment: I am sorry for saying the same things the whole time. If you have more questions, I suggest we move this discussion to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82234/discussion-between-felix-b-and-stan-tendijck).

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want to represent everything in terms of the $\sigma$-algebra notion of conditional expectation, then $E[X \mid A]$ where $A$ is a shorthand for $E[X \mid \sigma(1_A)](\omega)$ where $\omega$ is any element of $A$. The fact that $E[X \mid \sigma(1_A)]$ is $\sigma(1_A)$ measurable forces it to be constant on $A$ (indeed this is the generalization of your first property of $E[X \mid Y]$).

When $A$ is null you have to be a bit careful, however, because in this case your second property doesn't care about the values of $E[X \mid 1_A]$ on $A$ since they wash out upon integration. In this situation you generally need to use some kind of limiting setup: for example, to condition on $Y=y$ you might instead condition on $Y \in (y-\varepsilon,y+\varepsilon)$ and send $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: I am getting the feeling that our intro to probability theory prof went with a compromise when defining the conditional expectation. He didn't define it just with the densities as the definition would have been different for continuous and discrete random variables, but also not with sigma algebras (Like the wikipedia article on conditional expectation suggests). I think I see where the connection is (in the second condition the sets $\{Y\in B\}$ are the sets of $\sigma(Y)$) so maybe my issues come from there, because I have some issues understanding your notation

Comment: @FelixB. The definition you gave is essentially a special case of the $\sigma$-algebra definition, where instead of an arbitrary sub-$\sigma$-algebra of the given one, you consider only $\sigma$-algebras of the form $\sigma(Y)$. This consideration leads to your first property, which a nice intuitive way of thinking about the measurability requirement in the $\sigma$-algebra definition.